# Modman: symlink module from home directory

Tags: module, magento-1

If i have a module in my home directory:

```
/home/users/me/mymodule
```

and I have my web root in var/www

```
/var/www/mysite/public_html
```

How can i use modman to link the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `modman` file in `/home/users/me/mymodule` is configured properly

```
code                   app/code/local/My/Module/
frontend/layout/*      app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/
frontend/template      app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule
My_Module.xml          app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml
```

It defines files of your module, to which folders of your project will be linked.

You need to go to your project folder `/var/www/mysite/public_html`

```
cd /var/www/mysite/public_html
```

and run

```
/path/to/modman init
/path/to/modman link /home/users/me/mymodule
```

Anyway here is a [tutorial](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/wiki/Using-modman-without-git-or-svn) how to use modman without git and svn.